# Taking the nth list from a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, tuples, extract

I have the following function that returns a list of list of pairs.

```
getprofileMatrix :: Profile -> [[(Char, Int)]]
getprofileMatrix (Profile profileMatrix _ _ _) = profileMatrix
```

What I want to do is create a function that takes a `Profile`, an `Int` and a `Char` value and then looks in the list `[[(Char, Int)]]` and returns the nth list (the `Int` parameter value) that will look like this [(Char, Int)] and then looks for the `Char` in the list of tuples, and if my parameter `Char` value matches, then it returns the `Int` value of that tuple.

In order to get the Int value of a [(Char, Int)] list, I constructed the following function:

```
tupleNr :: Char -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
tupleNr letter list = head [nr | (ltr, nr) <- list, ltr == letter]
```

This function works as expected. My problem is when trying to extract the nth list from a [[(Char, Int]] and then applying the tupleNr function to it:

```
profileFrequency :: Profile -> Int -> Char -> Int
profileFrequency p i c = tupleNr c (map (\x -> (x !! i)).(getprofileMatrix p))
```

But it doesn't work.. I don't really understand why it doesn't work. First I call the `getprofileMatrix` function that returns the list `[[(Char, Int])]` from the `Profile` `p`. After that it maps my lambda function to extract the ith element from the list so that I get the single list `[(Char, Int)]`. And after that I apply the `tupleNr` function to get the `Int` value of the `[(Char, Int)]` list. I feel this should work but it doesn't.

I get the following error:

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Char, Int)]’
                with actual type ‘a0 -> [b0]’
    In the second argument of ‘tupleNr’, namely
      ‘(map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))’
    In the expression:
      tupleNr c (map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))
    In an equation for ‘profileFrequency’:
        profileFrequency p i c
          = tupleNr c (map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))


    Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> [[b0]]’
                with actual type ‘[[(Char, Int)]]’
    Possible cause: ‘getprofileMatrix’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(getprofileMatrix p)’
    In the second argument of ‘tupleNr’, namely
      ‘(map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))’
```

Sorry if I've not been clear enough, but hope anyone can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
profileFrequency :: Profile -> Int -> Char -> Int
profileFrequency p i c = tupleNr c (map (\x -> (x !! i)).(getprofileMatrix p))
```

with:

```
profileFrequency :: Profile -> Int -> Char -> Int
profileFrequency p i c = tupleNr c . map (!! i) . getprofileMatrix $ p
--                                 ^1    ^^^^^^2                  ^^^3
```

The problems were:

1. Function application has the precedence over composition, so in `tupleNr c (map (\x -> (x !! i))` you are passing `(map (\x -> (x !! i))`, which is a function, as the "second argument" of `tupleNr` which accepts a list instead. What you want is to compose `tupleNr c` and `(map (\x -> (x !! i))` instead.
2. Not really an issue, but `map (\x -> (x !! i)` is equivalent to `map (!! i)`, so you can refactor it to that. It's the same concept as `(+ 1)` being `(\i -> i + 1)`.
3. In the end, what you want is to pass `p` to a composed function (`tupleNr c . map (!! i) . getprofileMatrix`). That's not what you are doing: `(getprofileMatrix p)` is of type `[[(Char, Int)]]`, which is not a function type, so you can't compose it. Therefore you have to delay the application of `p` to after all functions have been composed.

Comment: Thanks for replying..! But I still get an error:
  Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘a0 -> Int’
    In the expression:
      tupleNr c . (map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))
    In an equation for ‘profileFrequency’:
        profileFrequency p i c
          = tupleNr c . (map (\ x -> (x !! i)) . (getprofileMatrix p))

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the added comments! Really appreciate it!